# Does anyone have any thought how come the fuzzy rules can be verified and validated?

Tags: data-mining, reference-request, fuzzy-logic

Fuzzy logic was utilized to derive a performance indicator of some manufacturing facilities in an uncertain environment. There are some historical data obtained from some manufacturing facilities’ rigorous assessments. How come can I use this data to verify and validate the fuzzy rules? Any insights and feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking of a programmatic implementation of Fuzzy Logic?

Comment: @ Dawny 33. I didn't exactly get that what you meant by "programmatic implementation of Fuzzy Logic". I'm using triangular membership function in Matlab for both input/output. However, I was thinking if there is any statistical or mathematical analysis to verify and validate the fuzzy rules rather than opinions' experts only.

Comment: Ohh okay.  I get it now.  I think it would be better if you added the reference-request tag.

Comment: Dawny, how can I add the reference-request tag?

Comment: It is already added :)